# Joining Lists of Lists of Strings

Tags: python, list

I've a list of lists, in which each element is a single character:

```
 ngrams = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']]
```

From this, I want to generate a new single list with the content `['aa','ab','ac','ba','bb','bc','ca','cb','cc']`.  The individual elements of each list are appended to each other but in reverse order of the lists.  I've come up with this (where `np = 2`):

```
for cnt in range(np-2,-1,-1):
  thisngrams[-1] = [a+b for (a,b) in zip(thisngrams[-1],thisngrams[cnt])]
```

My solution needs to handle `np` higher than just 2.  I expect this is O(np), which isn't bad.  Can someone suggest a more efficient and pythonic way to do what I want (or is this a good pythonic approach)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ngrams = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']]

new = map(''.join, zip(*ngrams))
```

Output:

```
['aa', 'ba', 'ca', 'ab', 'bb', 'cb', 'ac', 'bc', 'cc']
```

For more than two elements:

```
n = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g"]]

new = map(''.join, zip(* reversed(ngrams)))

#in Python3
#new = list(map(''.join, zip(* reversed(ngrams))))
```

Output:

```
['eaa', 'fcb', 'gdc']
```

Comment: Or `map(''.join, zip(*ngrams))` for more than two!

Comment: I think Ryan's got what you want, but if you also want to reverse the order of the list, you'll want `map(''.join, zip(* reversed(ngrams)))`

Comment: Thanks Carl, I just simply used the * to unpack ngrams[::-1] :-)

Comment: Thank you Ajax.  Python is so f'ing beautiful!